# React states are undefined after calling parent function with onClick

Tags: components

in the child component, whenever I click one of the mapped Span elements, the onClick triggers the switchLaunch function in the parent component and triggers the debugger I have there now for testing purposes.  However, all the states I had set are now undefined.  So when I call *this.state.allPastLaunches*, it's now undefined but if I call *this.allPastLaunches*, the data is there.  I'm confused as to where I'm going wrong

**Parent Component (App)**

```
class App extends Component {
  //api call for latest space launch
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedLaunch: "",
      launchData: "",
      videoURL: null,
      allPastLaunches: [],
      showVideo: false
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getLaunchData()
  }

  switchLaunch(launch) {
    debugger
    // ALL MY STATES ARE EMPTY HERE WHEN I TRY TO LOG THEM AFTER THE FUNCTION 
    IS TRIGGERED BY THE CHILD'S ONCLICK
  }


  getLaunchData() {
    // getting latest launch
    fetch('https://api.spalta.launch/launch')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({ 
          launchData: json,
          videoURL: json.links["video_link"],
          missionPatch: json.links["mission_patch"]
        });
      });

    //getting all previous launches
    fetch('https://api.spalta.launch/prevLaunches')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({ 
          allPastLaunches: json,
        });
      });

  }
  render() {
    let dataReady = this.state.videoURL;

    if (this.state.launchData != null) {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          {this.state.allPastLaunches ? 
             <Header 
               key="header"
               missionPatch = {this.state.missionPatch}
               allPastLaunches = {this.state.allPastLaunches}
               switchLaunch = {this.switchLaunch}
             />
           :
              <div>Loading...</div>
           }
```

**Child Component (Header)**

```
class Header extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
  }


  render() {

    var launches = this.props.allPastLaunches;

    var imgClass = classNames({
      'img-container': true,
      'animated': true,
      'fadeInDownBig': true
    });

    const component = this;

    return (
      <div key = "container" className="header-container">
        <div key = "img-container">
            {launches.map((launch, index) => 
                <span key = {index} onClick= {() => { component.props.switchLaunch(index) }} > 
                    {launch["rocket"].rocket_id}
                </span>

            )}
```

Comment: *edited it to show latest code I've tried.  Added in suggestion from mikeB to create a const to hold the scope of this and use it in the map but still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind your method so it has the correct context, you can read more about it here: https://www.andreasreiterer.at/web-development/bind-callback-function-react/

```
class App extends Component {
  //api call for latest space launch
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  // This line makes sure that "this" is the correct 
  // thing when this method is called via callback
  this.switchLaunch = this.switchLaunch.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      selectedLaunch: "",
      launchData: "",
      videoURL: null,
      allPastLaunches: [],
      showVideo: false
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getLaunchData()
  }

  switchLaunch(launch) {
    debugger
    // ALL MY STATES ARE EMPTY HERE WHEN I TRY TO LOG THEM AFTER THE FUNCTION 
    IS TRIGGERED BY THE CHILD'S ONCLICK
  }
...
```

Old Answer:

Try this:

```
const component = this
return (
      <div key = "container" className="header-container">
        <div key = "img-container">
            {launches.map((launch, index) => 
                <span key = {index} onClick= {() => { component.props.switchLaunch(index) }} > 
                    {launch["rocket"].rocket_id}
                </span>

            )}
```

The code `(launch, index) =>` creates a new function, so `this` is the context of the new function (i.e. the original `this` is hidden).  You need to save `this` as `component` and use it in the inner function.

Comment: still getting the same.  I added that and tried to log `this.state.videoURL` in switchLaunch function in the parent and it comes back with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'videoURL' of undefined`

Comment: sorry, just updated it and commented on what I attempted

Comment: See edit, that should do it `this.switchLaunch = this.switchLaunch.bind(this);` in constructor

Comment: bingo @mikeb , that worked.  If you don't mind, can you explain to me why this works and what I did wrong?

Comment: Added this link to another edit: https://www.andreasreiterer.at/web-development/bind-callback-function-react/